# Does the limit(colimit) have transitivity?

Tags: category-theory

For example, in $Set$:

[image]

The limit of $A$ and $B$ is $A \times B$;

The limit of $A \times B$ and $C$ is ($A \times B) \times C$;

The limit of $A$, $B$ and $C$ are $A \times B \times C$.

We know that ($A \times B) \times C \cong A \times B \times C$.

My question is:

Can this conclusion be generalized to any limit/colimit than product/coproduct?

I searched a conclusion on nlab, it give me a conclusion.

https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/preserved+limit#Examples

> limits preserve limits

https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/limits+commute+with+limits

> limits commute with limits

It seems to tell me Yes, but its explanation is a bit complicated for me. Since I am not a mathematician, so I want to confirm this fact.

---

Edit for making this question clearer.

Given a category $C$ and two diagrams $D : I \to C$ and $E : J \to C$, suppose the image of $I$ and $J$ are not overlapped and we know that $D$ and $E$ have limits (i.e. $\lim_D$ an $lim_E$). Now I can take the product of the two apex of $\lim_D$ an $\lim_E$ (suppose the product exists).

The question is:

Is there any relationship between $\lim_D \times \lim_E$ and $\lim_{D+E}$ ?

For example,

1. Does the $\lim_{D+E}$ exist, if $\lim_D \times \lim_E$ exist?
2. Does the apex of $\lim_D \times \lim_E$ isomorphic to $\lim_{D+E}$? I'm sorry, since I don't know how to compare two limits equipped with different cones, so I can only compare apex here. (In this case, the diagram of $\lim_{D+E}$ is $D+E$ on $C$ and the diagram of $\lim_D \times \lim_E$ is two objects.)

Thanks.

Comment: I think you should make your request clearer : for the product, the property you give is associativity (up to isomorphism), but this property doesn't make sense for general limits, unless you want to give it some precise meaning. In particular, the associativity condition you give here doesn't seem (at least at first glance) to be a special case of either "limits preserve limits" or "limits commute with limits"

Comment: @MaximeRamzi in fact, s/up to isomorphims/up to *canonical* isomorphism/

Comment: @MaximeRamzi I'm sorry, this question was indeed a bit confusing before. I edited this question to make it clearer.

Comment: A last clarification is needed : by $D+E$, do you mean the obvious functor indexed by $I+J$ (the coproduct of $I$ and $J$, which has a copy of $I$ and a copy of $J$ and no arrows between them) ?

Comment: @MaximeRamzi Yes, because the image of I and J are not overlapped.

Comment: That hypothesis is really not necessary; but at least with this clarification I can now answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer to the specific question is yes.

More precisely :

> Let $I,J$ be two categories, $F:I\to C, G: J\to C$ two functors. Let $I+J$ be the coproduct of $I,J$, that is, a category which consists of one copy of $I$ and one disjoint copy of $J$ with no morphisms inbetween; then let $K: I+J\to C$ be obtained from $F,G$ by the universal property of the coproduct.
>    Assume $\lim F$ and $\lim G$ exist. Then $\lim K$ exists if and only if $\lim F\times \lim G$ exists, in which case there is a canonical isomorphism between the two.

I won't dwell on what "canonical" means here, but hopefully it's clear from the statement (and/or the proof).

Proof : For notations, for $i\in I, p_i: \lim F\to F(i)$ is the canonical morphism, and similarly $q_j : \lim G\to G(j)$ for $j\in J$

Assume $P= \lim F\times \lim G$ exist, with projections $p$ to $\lim F$ and $q$ to $\lim G$. Then define for $k\in I+J$, $r_k : P\to K(k)$ by $p_i\circ p$ if $k=i\in I$, $q_j\circ q$ if $k=j\in J$.

I claim that this is a cone $P\to K$. To see this, note that any morphism in $I+J$ is either in $I$, or in $J$, in which case the cone property follows from that of $\lim F$, or $\lim G$.

Therefore $P$ is a cone. Moreover it is universal : let $C\to K$ be a cone. Then the restriction to $I$ is a cone $C\to F$, which induces a morphism $a : C\to \lim F$, and similarly by restricting to $J$ we get a map $b :C\to \lim G$. Using the universal property of products, we get $C\to P$. It's easy to check that it's a factorization of my cone.

It's also easy to check that any such factorization must be of this form, and therefore by uniqueness of the maps $C\to \lim F$ and $C\to \lim G$, this factorization is unique.

I'll  let you try to prove the converse, it's essentially the same kind of reasoning, not too hard - if you have trouble with it, don't hesitate to ask.

**Warning**:  here we saw that you if you have a category $L$ which can be written as $I+J$, then you can express the limit of $L$ as function of the limits on $I$ and $J$.

In general, it is difficult to relate the limit along a given category and the limits along categories that appear in a "decomposition" of said category - you have to know, in a good way, how those categories interact. Here, $I$ and $J$ essentially don't interact, which is what makes the description really easy.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, because there is some time difference. I have some trouble about proving the converse.

Comment: Assume $P=lim K$ exist, we can split the cone $P \to K$ to 2 cones, $P \to F$ and $P \to G$. Since $lim F$ is the universal cone for $F$, so it induces a unique morphism $p : P \to lim F$ (Similarly, $q : P \to lim G$).

Comment: Following your proof above, this apex P equipped with p and q should be the $lim F × lim G$, right?  Let C be a candidate apex equipped with $p': C \to limF$ and $q': C \to limG$, this two "projections" can induce a cone $C \to K$. Since $P \to K$ is universal cone, so there is unique morphism $m:C \to P$ , such that $p_i \circ p \circ m = p_i \circ p'$ and $q_j \circ q \circ m = q_j \circ q'$. But what we want to prove is $p \circ m = p'$ and $ q \circ m = q'$, I have troube about proving this equation. Thanks.

Comment: Well $p_i\circ p\circ m = p_i\circ p'$ *for all $i$* implies $p\circ m = p'$ (similarly for $q$), that's by unicity in the universal property

Comment: Great! But what is unicity? Could you give me some reference? I know one of the cancellation law about monomorphism, that is if $p_i$ is monomorphism, then $pi∘p∘m=pi∘p′ \Rightarrow p∘m=p'$, i.e we can cancel $p_i$ in the left. What you give me today a new cancellation law, it is really new thing to me! Is there any name for this cancellation law? Thanks.

Comment: Suppose you have a limit cone $(P,(p_i)_{i\in I}), p_i : P\to F(i)$, and suppose $f,g: C\to P$ are such that *for all* $i$, $p_i\circ f = p_i\circ g$. Denote this common value by, say $q_i$. It's easy to prove that $q_i :C\to F(i)$ is a cone. By the universal property of the limit, there is a *unique* morphism $h: C\to P$ such that for all $i, p_i\circ h = q_i$. But now $f,g$ are two such morphisms, so $f=g$, by unicity. This is the definition of limit

Comment: I got it, thanks! About the **Warning** and your comments below the question. You said that "That hypothesis is really not necessary". What is that mean? If the image of I and J are overlapped, does this conclusion also hold? The "overlap" means the diagram K in C may share objects of the image of I and J. The morphisms will be more complicated...

Comment: The hypothesis is not necessary because what matters in computing the limit is the indexing diagram - for instance if you have as  a category $I$ with two objects and no nonidentity morphisms, then you can still use this to compute $A\times A$, even though there is some overlap (the object $A$ is picked out twice). You should never really impose conditions of non overlapping at the target, they're usually not useful, because the domain (the indexing category) remembers the difference

Comment: OK. I undertand what you mean. Thanks again!

Comment: Sorry, I have another question to disturb you... If I take $colim G$ rather than $lim G$, then product them. We get $lim G \times colim G$, if it exist. Is there an official name about this construction or is there any relationship between $lim G \times colim G$ and some universal construction on $K$. If this question too big, I will create another new question.

Comment: I don't know, it doesn't ring a bell to me. Mixing limits and colimits is usually complicated. If you're interested you should create another question, with more details about the construction