# Is there any theory about mix limit and colimit?

Tags: reference-request, category-theory

Given a category $C$ and two diagrams $D:I→C$ and $E:J→C$, suppose the image of $I$ and $J$ are not overlapped and we know that $D$ has limit, $E$ has colimit, i.e. $lim D$ and $colim E$. Now I can take the product of the two apex of $lim D$ an $colim E$, i.e. $lim D \times colim E$ (suppose the product exists).

The question is:

1. Is there any theory about this kind of construction $lim D \times colim E$? (It mix limit and colimt.)
2. Is there any relationship between $lim D \times colim E$ and some universal construction on the diagram $D+E$? The diagram $D+E$ means the obvious functor indexed by $I+J$ (the coproduct of $I$ and $J$, which has a copy of $I$ and a copy of $J$ and no arrows between them).

Background:

This question inspired by the previous quesiton [Does the limit(colimit) have transitivity?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3612719/does-the-limitcolimit-have-transitivity). In that quesiton, following Maxime Ramzi's answer, we have a conclusion. That is $lim (D+E)$ exists if and only if $lim D × lim E$ exists, in which case there is a canonical isomorphism between the two. But here, we take $colim E$ instead of  $lim E$.

Thanks.

Comment: Why shouldn’t the images “overlap”?

Comment: @KevinCarlson Yes, this condition is not necessary, just for drawing convenience. Detail see https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3612719/does-the-limitcolimit-have-transitivity

Comment: In full generality, I think the answer to this question is no. Mixing colimits and limits is bad, because the resulting object is now one you don't understand. We understand morphisms into colimits and we understand morphisms out of limits. We understand very little about morphisms into colimits in general, and since you've taken a product of the limit and the colimit, this is the obstacle we face in understanding this object. If you make some assumptions you can sometimes get information like [these commutativity results](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/commutativity+of+limits+and+colimits).